# Python Data Frame summary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe (df table below):
Every user can post in any category. I have to calculate HOW MANY DISTINCT USERS has a post in category A and at the same time has posts in categories, B, C and D. Table like:

| User | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 33 | B |
| 33 | C |
| 33 | D |
| 54 | A |
| 54 | B |
| 87 | A |
| 87 | B |
| 87 | C |
| 87 | D |

Total table is 950,000 rows It either gives Nan results in pivot (variant 1) or memory overflow (variant 2). Necessary result is

| Category | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| D | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

Diagonal: A-B-C-D - total posted in each category, lower and upper triangles are the same and are intersections of how many users posted in, for instance, B and C.

I have tried

1. df.pivot_table(values=['user','category'],index=['category'], columns=['category'],aggfunc=np.count_nonzero)
2. a = df.values

d = {(i, j): np.mean(a[:, i] == a[:, j]) for i, j in combinations(range(a.shape[1]), 2)}

res, c, vals = np.zeros((a.shape[1], a.shape[1])), 
list(map(list, zip(*d.keys()))), list(d.values())

res[c[0], c[1]] = vals

res_df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)

Would yo please help with ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is use `merge` with `crosstab` like:

```
df = df.merge(df, on='User')
df = pd.crosstab(df['Category_x'], df['Category_y'])
print (df)
Category_y  A  B  C  D
Category_x            
A           3  3  1  1
B           3  4  2  2
C           1  2  2  2
D           1  2  2  2
```